# Efficient estimation of conditional probability density

Tags: estimation, dataset, density-function, conditional

The formulation of the conditional density is:
$$ f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}. $$

I need to estimate this density from data and it's prohibitively time-consuming to calculate the joint density (I have 10s of variables). However, for fixed values of x, it is easy to estimate directly the conditional density (without calculating the joint). I also have access to the df of X and its inverse, $F_X$, $F_X^{-1}$. My approach to estimate the conditional density is then to calculate this:
$$ \hat{f_{Y|X}(y|x)} \overset{?}= \frac{\sum_i f_{Y|X}(y|x=F_X^{-1}(i))}{NF}, $$
where $i$ takes a range of quantiles (for example $n$ evenly spaced points between 0 and 1) and NF is a normalization factor to ensure the density integrates to 1.

I admit not having any solid understanding of why I did this, but if someone can atleast point me to some resources, it would be greatly appreciated.

Extra non-relevant note: the densities in question are actually copula-densities, but it should not alter any of the equations.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the problem you are trying to solve by doing this? I'm asking, because you seem to be re-inventing the wheel here, as there are many known solutions for estimating conditional distributions or properties of such distributions.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am estimating empirical copulas from data using the beta kernel as described in Chen 1999 (Beta kernel estimators for density functions). Estimating the complete joint density is time-consuming as its time-complexity is exponential in number of variables. However, it's possible to calculate the univariate density for variable $x_1$ for fixed values of all other variables $x_i$ in polynomial time.

Comment: Addendum:

Since I can calculate the conditional density for fixed points of the conditioned variable ($x$ in the question), I have thus far used the expected value of $X$ only. I want to calculate the conditional density of $Y$ given multiple values of $X$.